# javascript remove function not valid

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to debug this function in Firefox/Firebug and it says that "dbasedata.remove" is not a function??

```
function dbasetype(){

var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
        dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
        dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");
        dbasedata = dbasedata.remove("UK_CONTACTS","");

if (dbasedata != "") {
        _area.value = _dbase_name.value;            
    } }
```

Comment: Firebug is correct. There is no such method. You probably want `replace()`.

Comment: I agree with Firebug, what are you trying to accomplish with 'dbasedata.remove("UK_CONTACTS","")' ?

Comment: dbasedata contains the value of the object _dbase_name. Do you want to remove the object or edit it's value?

Comment: I want to remove UK_CONTACTS from the string so I can test if there is any data left in the string.

Comment: Use `replace()`. If you replace something with an empty string it's effectively removing it. Or if all you want is to check if it has some specific value, just test for it directly: `if( dbasedata == "UK_CONTACTS" ) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because JavaScript strings have no such method as `remove()`.

You can see the available methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2).

If you want to replace "UK_CONTACTS" with "" then see the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method instead:

```
dbasedata = dbasedata.replace("UK_CONTACTS","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/UK_CONTACTS/, "");
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

A string object does not have a Remove() function. Firebug is correct. You might want to use replace() instead:

```
function dbasetype(){

var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
        dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
        dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");
        dbasedata = dbasedata.replace("UK_CONTACTS","");

if (dbasedata != "") {
        _area.value = _dbase_name.value;            
    } }
```